Is the capacitance obtained using the RC circuit equation the correct value?
To find the dielectric constant of the dielectric according to frequency, an RC circuit was constructed and the capacitance was calculated using the RC circuit equation using the voltage applied to R, the input voltage, and the frequency using an oscilloscope.
To eliminate the fringe effect, we tried to reduce the error by calculating the capacitance of the part where the electric field of the circular capacitor was uniform and subtracting the remaining part.
However, sometimes the capacitance in the fringe area became negative.
So, I am worried. Is calculating using the RC circuit formula the right way for this experiment?

To eliminate the fringe effect, we tried to reduce the error by calculating the capacitance of the part where the electric field of the circular capacitor was uniform and subtracting the remaining part. How did you do this?

The experiment itself is an experiment that follows the reference paper to some extent, and according to the Laplace equation calculated in the paper, the area inside 0.6 times the radius of the circular capacitor was set as the uniform electric field area. Originally, I was supposed to use an LRC meter, but since I didn't have an LRC meter, I constructed an RC circuit, measured the voltage with an oscilloscope, and calculated the capacitance by deriving it through the equation to find the impedance of the RC circuit.

What paper? You didn’t provide any reference to a paper.

Sorry, it's my first time using this site, so I didn't know if I could just say the title of the paper. The title of the paper is 
